# truncate() on FAT32

Tags: linux, truncate, fat32

I noticed a big performance difference in the `truncate()` and `ftruncate()` function call when the file lives either on a ext3 filesystem or on a FAT32 filesystem.

The file is about 50 MiB. To remove about 100 Byte of data from that file I use

```
ftruncate(file, fsize - num_bytes)
```

It works fine but when operating on a FAT32 filesystem the performance is much worse:

```
 truncate on ext3      Time needed: 0.000030s
 truncate on FAT32     Time needed: 3.877204s
```

I have run the tests multiple times with allways similar results. Sometimes the FAT results were even worse (~ 7s).

My question is: **what does FAT32 do to the file, that it takes so long?**

My first assumption was, that it has to rewrite the whole file, but even the generation/initialization of that file doesn't take so long (~ 1.5s).

I ran it on a 64 Bit Linux system and compiled with:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -O0 -g3 -pg -pedantic -Wall
```

Comment: See http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/683607.

Comment: @Frédéric The link is about truncate-extend. I am talking about shrinking the size. Which should be a different operation, I think.

Comment: Look at it with `ltrace`.